# Prestashop Module Form creation

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

I want to add 21 checkboxes and a text field(Name) in a good design way. Also there must be "check all button" to check all the checkboxes, how to do it in module PHP page in prestashop.

Since I am new to prestashop I don't know about the form submission, I have to save these two fields together as a json array in database.

Is that possible in prestashop? please help me regarding this.

prestashop version = 1.6

Thanks in advance

**Sample code**

```
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l( 'Generate Export Order Settings' ),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'display',
                'values' => array(
                    'query' => array(
                        array(
                            'id' => 'all_fields',
                            'name' => $this->l('All Fields'),
                            'val' => '1'                                
                        ),
                    ),
                    'id' => 'id',
                    'name' => 'name'
                )
            ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l( 'Save Export Settings' ),
                'class' => 'button pull-right',
                'name' => 'save-main-display-settings',
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

I don't know how to add check box in 3 columns and 7 rows and select all button to select all the checkbox.

Comment: Please share your code, so that people over here can help you...

Comment: Hello. Where do you need to display this form, in module config, in prestashop front...?? It is better if you write your code and ask for your specific problem in it.

Comment: yes i want the form to be in module config

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS code to add check all functionality:

```
$('.chk_boxes').click(function(){
    var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
    $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',chk);
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HBGzy/

Comment: what about the checkboxes(3 columns and 7 rows)??? Actually I want to write it in  prestashop module config php page